# AngularJS standard directive priority list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking for a list of standard angularjs directives with their priorities (especially the nonzero ones). It would be helpful to look at it whenever you want to create a special directive, for example one with `terminal: true`, to see where it would fit best, but also to better understand how the angular designers meant for their directives to be used.

I know each directive has its priority specified in its documentation page, but that does not help to have a whole picture of the compile/link order, as a list like the one below would:

```
Directive  - Prio
-----------------
ng-repeat  - 1000
ng-if      -  600
ng-include -  400
...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

List of standard angular directives sorted by their priorities. Hope this will be useful.

```
Directive           Priority    
---------------     -----------
ng-switch           1200    
ng-non-bindable     1000    
ng-repeat           1000    
ng-if               600 
ng-controller       500 
ng-init             450 
ng-include          400 
ng-checked          100 
ng-disabled         100 
ng-open             100 
ng-readonly         100 
ng-selected         100 
ng-href             99  
ng-src              99  
ng-srcset           99  
ng-model            1   
ng-app              0   
ng-bind             0   
ng-bind-html        0   
ng-bind-template    0
ng-blur             0
ng-change           0
ng-class            0
ng-class-even       0
ng-class-odd        0
ng-click            0
ng-cloak            0
ng-copy             0
ng-csp              0
ng-cut              0
ng-dbl-click        0
ng-focus            0
ng-form             0
ng-hide             0
ng-keydown          0
ng-keypress         0
ng-keyup            0
ng-list             0
ng-model-options    0
ng-mousedown        0
ng-mouseenter       0
ng-mouseleave       0
ng-mousemove        0
ng-mouseover        0
ng-mouseup          0
ng-options          0
ng-paste            0
ng-pluralize        0
ng-show             0
ng-style            0
ng-submit           0
ng-transclude       0
ng-value            0
```

**References**

- [AngularJS 1.5.0 Source](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js)

Comment: Is it possible to add the reference of this answer ?

Comment: @HocineDJEMAI I've added a reference to the source. Search for `priority:` to verify.